# Can I "use" an alternative ki-focus to the one I make an attack with?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, attack

I know usually you have to decide whether you use your ki focus or your enchantment on your weapon to decide damage and special effects.

However I couldn't help to notice that in some of the text of the ki foci there is no specification that you have to make an attack using the particular ki focus like in: scavengers bird it doesn't tell you for the at will power that you have to make the attack using the ki focus the same goes for emerald flames daily power. Unlike for example deathstrike where it is specified that you have to make an attack using the ki focus.

So my question is if I equip a ki focus like scavengers bird and make an attack with the enchantment bonus and not with the ki focus will i still be able to use the at-will power of the scavengers bird ki focus?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, note that you must attune yourself to a Ki Focus during a short or extended rest, so you can't just choose to equip or unequip a Ki Focus in the middle of combat- you're stuck with it until your next rest (this is part of the Ki Focus rules, Heroes of Shadow 159 and Mordenkainen's Magnificient Emporium 44 for the most updated ones).

With that said, there are some Ki Foci that do not require attacking with them to get their powers, and Scavenger Bird is one of them.  The best known Ki Focus to do this with is Rain of Hammers- an always on damage to an adjacent creature when you drop an enemy to 0, and a daily minor action attack (to use any at will that you know) make it particularly powerful, and a good choice for those who gain Ki Foci through a multiclass feat that they're taking for some other reason.